# Navigation Settings csom Powershell for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, navigation

I need to do scripts to set navigation for my publish sharepoint Online using CSOM PowerShell:
Navigation Settings mean the same as Native Navigation Settings:

```
Global Navigation:(chose the top-level site,Managed Navigation and Structural Navigation)
Current Navigation:(chose the top-level site,Managed Navigation, Structural Navigation and Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site)
```

and the same as `Managed Navigation: Term Set`

with c# I use this logic

```
    webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.InheritFromParentWeb;
webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.Unknown;
webNavigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.Unknown;



pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentDynamicChildLimit = 20;
```

but with powershell seems to be not the same.
Any one know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation`

You can change the values of the navigation source as per your requirement.

See below screenshot:

[image]

Try the below code in powershell:

```
#Credentials to connect to office 365 site collection url 
$url ="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/home"
$username="user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password="yourpassword"
$Password = $password |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force

Write-Host "Load CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll")

Write-Host "CSOM libraries loaded successfully" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green 

Write-Host "authenticate to SharePoint Online Tenant site $url and get ClientContext object" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  Write-Host "authenticateed to SharePoint Online Tenant site $url and get ClientContext object succeefully" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Not able to authenticateed to SharePoint Online $_.Exception.Message" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
  return
}

#set both current and global navigation settings to structural
Write-Host "set both current and global navigation settings to structural started" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
$taxonomySession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($context)
$navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $context, $context.Web

#set both current and global navigation settings to structural
$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = "portalProvider"
$navigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = "portalProvider"

#For Display the same navigation items as the parent site
#$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = "inheritFromParentWeb"
#$navigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = "inheritFromParentWeb"

#For Managed Navigation
#$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = "taxonomyProvider"
#$navigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = "taxonomyProvider"

$navigationSettings.Update($taxonomySession)

try
{
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "setting both current and global navigation settings to structural Completed" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green
}
catch
{
Write-Host "Error while setting both current and global navigation settings to structural" $_.Exception.Message -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
}


// disable quick launch navigation including subsites and pages    
$context.Load($web.AllProperties)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$web.AllProperties["__IncludeSubSitesInNavigation"] = "False"
$web.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$web.AllProperties["__IncludePagesInNavigation"] = "False"
$web.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#set dynamic child limit for current navigation
$web.AllProperties["__CurrentDynamicChildLimit"] = 20
$web.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#set dynamic child limit for global navigation
#$web.AllProperties["__GlobalDynamicChildLimit"] = 20
#$web.Update()
#$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: thanks, Gautam .works fine for CurrentNavigation.Source but for $props.FieldValues doesnt work ! any idea

Comment: can you check now ? i forgot to load property bag value. Have updated the code.

Comment: could not found __IncludeSubSitesInNavigation and __IncludePagesInNavigation

Comment: check now. have edited how we update property bag value

Comment: Big thanks Gautam now it works fine , you save my life Man :)

Comment: Above powershell script not working for me.
I am getting error on this line $navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $context, $context.Web ERROR DETAILS: "cannot find an overload for web navigation settings"