# PowerShell WebNavigationSettings not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, pnp-powershell

Web is full of articles explaining how to modify SharePoint Online SPWeb navigation settings such as

- [Navigation Settings csom Powershell for SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202858/navigation-settings-csom-powershell-for-sharepoint-online)
- https://sharepointycl.wordpress.com/2017/01/27/updating-managed-navigation-settings-for-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/
- https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/blob/master/Components/Core.TaxonomyNavigationComponents/Utility/Navigation.ps1

But for some reason the line

```
$navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $ctx, $web
```

throws me error

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "WebNavigationSettings" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Work\SharePoint\ModifySiteNavigationSettings.ps1:51 char:27
+ ... nSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigat ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I've tried with both [SP Online Client Components SDKs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True) 16.0.6906.1200 (latest) and 16.0.6518.1200, but error stays the same.

dotPeeking the *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing* assembly contains the below, so it's not about the number of arguments.

```
public WebNavigationSettings(ClientRuntimeContext context, Web web)
```

Any tips what could be causing this and how to make it work?

Here's my full code

```
param(
       [string]$siteUrl,
       [string]$username,
       [string]$password
)

$path = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\"
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll")

if (-not $siteUrl)
{
    Write-Host "Specify site url in siteUrl parameter" -foregroundcolor red
    return
}

if (-not $username)
{
    Write-Host "Specify user name in username parameter" -foregroundcolor red
    return
}

if (-not $password)
{
    Write-Host "Specify user password in password parameter" -foregroundcolor red
    return
}

function Inherit-Navigation-For-Web($ctx, $web, $taxSession)
{
    Write-Host "Inherit navigation for" $web.Url -foregroundcolor green
    $ctx.Load($web)
    $web.AllProperties["__CurrentNavigationIncludeTypes"] = 0
    $web.Update()
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

    $navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $ctx, $web # <<< ERROR COMES HERE

    $navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.CurrentNavigationSource]::PortalProvider
    $navigationSettings.Update($taxSession)

    Write-Host "    Navigation is updated" -foregroundcolor green

    $ctx.Load($web.Webs)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $web.Webs | ForEach-Object { Inherit-Navigation-For-Web $ctx $_ $taxSession }  
}

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.RequestTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
$ctx.AuthenticationMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode]::Default
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
#$ctx.Load($ctx.Site)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$taxSession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($ctx)

Inherit-Navigation-For-Web $ctx $ctx.Web $taxSession
```

You execute it with

```
.\ModifySiteNavigationSettings.ps1 "https://tenant.sharepoint.com" "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" "password"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was conflict with v15 assemblies, although I explicitly did Add-Type from 16 hive. Deleting Client assemblies from 15 hive's ISAPI folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma, get coffee :)

Simply modify the line as below, should work :

```
$navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $ctx, $web
```

**Update**: Looks like there is some issue.Try it as below:

```
$navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $ctx, $web 
$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = "portalProvider"
$navigationSettings.Update($taxSession)
```

or

```
$navigationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings $ctx, $web 
$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource]::PortalProvider
$navigationSettings.Update($taxSession)
```

Comment: Thanks, will get yet another cup :D However, I originally had another error, so the missing comma (and thus error) was just a result of me troubleshooting. Updated the question with the original error that comes even when I have comma.

Comment: Just saw your answer , glad that it worked :) . I tried your code however it throws error at the line `$navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.CurrentNavigationSource]::PortalProvider`, so have modified it. I have used the latest CSOM dlls as well.

Comment: You're correct, it needed to be [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNa‌​vigationSource]::Por‌​talProvider] instead of [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.CurrentNa‌​vigationSource]::Por‌​talProvider], one other remnant from troubleshooting.